# Looping through a dictionary and tracking key depth

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I am looking to compare two dictionaries. The goal is to find out what keys exist in before, but not after (lost), and what values changed within matching keys (changed)

I have a pseudo-working script, but the issue is it does not show all keys that the changed key/value pairs belongs to.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

def new_keys(d1, d2, result={}):
    for key in d1.keys():
        if not d2.has_key(key):
            result[key] = d1[key]
        else:
            if isinstance(d1[key], dict) and isinstance(d2[key], dict):
                new_keys(d1[key], d2[key], result)
            else:
                if d1[key] != d2[key]:
                    result[key] = d2[key]

    return result

with open("before.json") as data_file:
    before = json.loads(data_file.read())

with open("after.json") as data_file:
    after = json.loads(data_file.read())

pprint(new_keys(before,after))
```

The current results are:

```
{u'1.1.1.1/32': {u'directlyConnected': True,
                 u'hardwareProgrammed': True,
                 u'kernelProgrammed': True,
                 u'routeAction': u'drop',
                 u'routeType': u'static',
                 u'vias': []},
```

An example result I want is: (it's a different route 0.0.0.0/0 instead of 1.1.1.1/32) but notice that it is nested within vrfs, default, routes keys.

```
{u'vrfs': {u'default': {u'allRoutesProgrammedHardware': True,
                        u'allRoutesProgrammedKernel': True,
                        u'defaultRouteState': u'reachable',
                        u'routes': {u'0.0.0.0/0': {u'directlyConnected': False,
                                                   u'hardwareProgrammed': True,
                                                   u'kernelProgrammed': True,
                                                   u'metric': 0,
                                                   u'preference': 1,
                                                   u'routeAction': u'forward',
                                                   u'routeType': u'static',
                                                   u'vias': [{u'interface': u'Management1',
                                                              u'nexthopAddr': u'10.31.32.1'}]},
```

I suspect I need to somehow track the keys as I step deeper but I'm having difficulty coding it appropriately.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Example JSON

```
{
    "vrfs": {
        "default": {
            "routes": {
                "2.2.2.2/32": {
                    "kernelProgrammed": true, 
                    "directlyConnected": true, 
                    "routeAction": "forward", 
                    "vias": [
                        {
                            "interface": "Ethernet4"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "hardwareProgrammed": true, 
                    "routeType": "static"
                }
            }, 
            "allRoutesProgrammedKernel": true, 
            "routingDisabled": false, 
            "allRoutesProgrammedHardware": true, 
            "defaultRouteState": "reachable"
        }
    }
}
```

After -

```
{
    "vrfs": {
        "default": {
            "routes": {
                "2.2.2.2/32": {
                    "kernelProgrammed": true, 
                    "directlyConnected": true, 
                    "routeAction": "forward", 
                    "vias": [
                        {
                            "interface": "Ethernet9"
                        }
                    ], 
                    "hardwareProgrammed": true, 
                    "routeType": "static"
                }
            }, 
            "allRoutesProgrammedKernel": true, 
            "routingDisabled": false, 
            "allRoutesProgrammedHardware": true, 
            "defaultRouteState": "reachable"
        }
    }
}
```

The interface value has changed.

Comment: Since you want nested dict, you should not pass the same `result` dict around. So for every call to `new_keys()` you should pass in a new `result` dict and then store the value in the caller iteration.

if you can post a sample after and before json might be helpful

Comment: @WreckeR I have added example json data for before/after. This is my first python script, so if you could possibly show me example code to explain your point, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a possible solution based on my comment above. Also some pythonic improvements. Use `iteritems()` and `key not in dict`.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

def new_keys(d1, d2, result={}):
    for key, d1_val in d1.iteritems():
        if key not in d2:
            result[key] = d1_val
        else:
            if isinstance(d1_val, dict) and isinstance(d2[key], dict):
                # Don't pass result.
                new_result = {}
                new_keys(d1[key], d2[key], new_result)
                # If new_result is not empty
                if new_result:
                   result[key] = new_result
            else:
                if d1_val != d2[key]:
                   result[key] = d1_val

    return result

with open("before.json") as data_file:
    before = json.loads(data_file.read())

with open("after.json") as data_file:
    after = json.loads(data_file.read())
pprint(new_keys(before,after))
```

With your sample before and after json this is what i get

```
{u'vrfs': {u'default': {u'routes': {u'2.2.2.2/32': {u'vias': [{u'interface': u'Ethernet4'}]}}}}}
```

Comment: I don't see how the recursion in this example is going to work and track the depth appropriately.

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong, maybe a paste mistake, but I was getting different output.

Comment: The key here is `new_result`. If any point in the recursion, new_result is not empty, every path up the tree will now have a non-empty `new_result`

Comment: I have updated my code after I saw your sample. Also I had to explicity pass in an empty `result` to every call to `new_keys()` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks Wrecker. This is great.

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you also please mark my answer as accepted. appreciate the reputation points.